# flatpak compile depedencies - permissions denied

Tags: linux, compilation, guile, flatpak

I'm creating a `flatpak` package for `vlc`. Since `flatpak` runs in sandbox and `vlc` depends on `lua` -> `guile` -> `bdw-gc` -> `libunistring`.

I have to first compile all these dependencies into `flatpak` sandbox. However `bdw-gc` and ``` libunistring`` compile perfectly, but ```guile`fails in last step of`make` with error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/run/build/guile'
stripping /home/ivansek/projects/vlc/flatpak/vlc-repo2/files/bin/guile to /home/ivansek/projects/vlc/flatpak/vlc-repo2/files/lib/debug/bin/guile.debug
stripping /home/ivansek/projects/vlc/flatpak/vlc-repo2/files/lib/libguile-2.0.so.22.8.1 to /home/ivansek/projects/vlc/flatpak/vlc-repo2/files/lib/debug/lib/libguile-2.0.so.22.8.1.debug
Error: module guile: Error opening file '/home/ivansek/projects/vlc/flatpak/vlc-repo2/files/lib/debug/source/guile/libguile/scmconfig.h': Permission denied
```

I'm using `flatpak-builder` for that using manifest file as:

```
{
   "app-id": "org.gnome.vlc",
   "runtime": "org.gnome.Platform",
   "runtime-version": "3.22",
   "sdk": "org.gnome.Sdk",
   "command": "vlc",
   "finish-args": [
       "--socket=x11",
       "--share=network",
       "--share=ipc",
       "--filesystems=host"
   ],
   "modules": [
      {
          "name": "bdw-gc",
          "sources": [
             {
                 "type": "archive",
                 "url": "http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gc_source/gc-7.6.0.tar.gz",
                 "sha256": "a14a28b1129be90e55cd6f71127ffc5594e1091d5d54131528c24cd0c03b7d90"        
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "name": "libunistring",
          "sources": [
             {
                 "type": "archive",
                 "url": "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libunistring/libunistring-0.9.6.tar.xz",
                 "sha256": "2df42eae46743e3f91201bf5c100041540a7704e8b9abfd57c972b2d544de41b"
             }
         ]
       },
       {
          "name": "guile",
          "sources": [
             {
                 "type": "archive",
                 "url": "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/guile/guile-2.0.13.tar.xz",
                 "sha256": "3744f2addc282a0de627aaef048f062982b44564d54ac31ff5217972529ed88b"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "name": "autogen",
          "sources": [
             {
                 "type": "archive",
                 "url": "https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autogen/rel5.18/autogen-5.18.tar.xz",
                 "sha256": "0c2dce22d4306ea29a01f6e54a35ea2b42dc7cf14f9818057b785e375bfbb784"
             }
         ]
       },
       {
           "name": "lua",
           "sources": [
              {
                  "type": "archive",
                  "url": "https://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.3.tar.gz",
                  "sha256": "5113c06884f7de453ce57702abaac1d618307f33f6789fa870e87a59d772aca2"
              }
           ]
       },
       {
           "name": "vlc",
           "sources": [
             {
                  "type": "archive",
                  "url": "http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.4/vlc-2.2.4.tar.xz",
                  "sha256": "1632e91d2a0087e0ef4c3fb4c95c3c2890f7715a9d1d43ffd46329f428cf53be"
             }
          ]
       }
   ]
}
```

How can I solve this problem, or what is another approach to include vlc in flatpak?